# Xcode Swift CocoaPods pod spec lint Fails on Embed Pods Frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I'm getting the following error when trying to run `pod spec lint --verbose`:

```
sent 1312397 bytes  received 106 bytes  2625006.00 bytes/sec
total size is 1311832  speedup is 1.00
/var/folders/3d/v0m_90ty4mg1opbynpnjjvzh2010gm/T/CocoaPods-Lint-20181015-62030-oljqd-MySwiftPackage/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App-frameworks.sh: line 104: EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: unbound variable
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

    ** BUILD FAILED **


    The following build commands failed:
        PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-loplmnuztwibrzfqgadqoxucytrz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release/App.build/Script-09EB8340PON5K18DNW0C63DQ.sh
    (1 failure)
   Testing with `xcodebuild`. 
 -> MySwiftPackage (0.1.0)
    - WARN  | summary: The summary is not meaningful.
    - WARN  | description: The description is shorter than the summary.
    - WARN  | url: The URL (https://github.com/fishcharlie/MySwiftPackage) is not reachable.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file. (in target 'App')
    - WARN  | xcodebuild:  MySwiftPackage/MySwiftPackage/ViewControllers/Shared/MyFirstViewController.swift:102:37: warning: conditional cast from 'UIViewController' to 'MyViewController' (aka 'UIViewController') always succeeds
    - WARN  | xcodebuild:  MySwiftPackage/MySwiftPackage/ViewControllers/Shared/MySecondViewController.swift:145:37: warning: conditional cast from 'UIViewController' to 'MyViewController' (aka 'UIViewController') always succeeds
    - ERROR | [OSX] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 5 warnings.
```

I know I have a few warnings that I can clean up. But there is only one error that I'm getting, which is `- ERROR | [OSX] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.`. And above that it says that `Embed Pods Frameworks` was the cause of failure.

Not quire sure how to debug this since I can build and run the example projects in Xcode just fine.

Below I have attached my Podspec as well.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MySwiftPackage'
  s.version          = '0.1.0'
  s.summary          = 'A short description of MySwiftPackage.'

  s.description      = <<-DESC
TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                       DESC

  s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/fishcharlie/MySwiftPackage'
  s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'fishcharlie' => 'fishcharlie.code@gmail.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/fishcharlie/MySwiftPackage.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
  s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/char_fish'

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
  s.osx.deployment_target = '10.11'
  s.swift_version = '4.2'

  s.source_files = 'MySwiftPackage/Classes/**/*', 'MySwiftPackage/ViewControllers/Shared/**/*'
  s.ios.source_files = 'MySwiftPackage/ViewControllers/iOS/**/*'
  s.osx.source_files = 'MySwiftPackage/ViewControllers/macOS/**/*'
  s.resources = 'MySwiftPackage/Assets/**/*.{ttf,xcassets}'

  s.dependency 'Alamofire', '4.7.3'
  s.dependency 'Bond', '6.10.2'
  s.ios.dependency '1PasswordExtension', '1.8.5'
end
```

Any ideas on how to fix/debug this?

Comment: What is your cocoapod version? Looks like they fixed this for xcode 10 in pr https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7720, you could try upgrading to 1.6.0

Comment: @JohnOttenlips I believe 1.6.0 is in beta, and would prefer not to upgrade to a beta version. I'm running version 1.5.3 tho.

Comment: You could try Xcode 9.4

Comment: just a suggestion, resolve warnings first. I faced same issue and when I added summary, description and and URL(valid git url) as mentioned in `s.source`. I was able to compile successfully

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the flag `--no-clean`.  This flag makes lint leave the build directory
                                                      intact for inspection
so you can debug that build failure in a workspace which may be more familiar and give you more information.

Looks like they fixed this for xcode 10 in pr github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7720, you could try upgrading to 1.6.0, or downgrading xcode to 9.4.

Comment: Tried that, and opened the workspace in Xcode and built it with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

The error should be about
`line 104: EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY: unbound variable`

The solution (as stated in [Issue 7708 on github/Cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7708) ) should be to add the following User-Defined Settings to project:

```
EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="-"
EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME="-"`
```

Comment: Where exactly do I put those? I'm pretty sure CocoaPods creates an entirely new workspace and such for the command I'm trying to run.

Comment: You can create a xxx.xcconfig file, with a first row `#include "./Pods/Pods.xcconfig"` and change the configuration settings file in Xcode project settings [how to add custom environment variables...](http://viteinfinite.com/2013/05/how-to-add-custom-environment-variables-in-xcode-and-cocoapods/)